# How to place markup.html from structured data markup in a Wordpress page

Tags: html, wordpress, structured-data

My Google analytics account suggested I add Structured Data markup to my web pages in the Head section.  I tagged the content I wanted and created the HTML.  However, when I go to place that code in the HTML on the page I tagged, I **do not** see a Head section.  So, I just put it in the top of the page.  When I add it to the top of the page it creates a space.  Would it be okay to place this code at the bottom of the page.  Code looks like this:

```
 <!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
 <script type="application/ld+json">
 [ {
 "@context" : "http://schema.org",
 "@type" : "Product",
  "description" : "IT Training Courses",
  "url" : "https://mindiq.com/it-training-course-list-application- 
   development- 
    java/"
    }, {
   "@context" : "http://schema.org",
   "@type" : "Product",
  "description" : "IT Training Courses",
  "url" : "https://mindiq.com/pythonl-training-onsite-tailored-low-cost/"
   } ]
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
?>
```

In `functions.php`, create your_function() with your structure data HTML in it and that function should load it in the `<head>`

```
function your_function() {
?>
 <!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
 <script type="application/ld+json">
 [ {
 "@context" : "http://schema.org",
 "@type" : "Product",
  "description" : "IT Training Courses",
  "url" : "https://mindiq.com/it-training-course-list-application- 
   development- 
    java/"
    }, {
   "@context" : "http://schema.org",
   "@type" : "Product",
  "description" : "IT Training Courses",
  "url" : "https://mindiq.com/pythonl-training-onsite-tailored-low-cost/"
   } ]
  </script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
```